# How old was Icheb in Star Trek Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

I haven't found any information online, but maybe I just didn't look close enough. How old was he when he joined the crew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, we don't know. He appears to be an older teenager when the crew first meet him in 2376 (the actor was actually 21 at the time of filming) but the episode describes him as having spent time in a "*maturation chamber*".

Since we have have no idea what the effect this would have on his physical maturity, nor the growth rate of his species, we're left with precious little evidence from the episodes.

Seven refers to him as a "*neonatal*" (newly born) drone and says he should have remained in a maturation chamber. It would appear that, in her judgement, he's not yet achieved his full adult growth.

> **SEVEN:** *You are neonatal drones. You should still be in maturation chambers.*
>
> **LEADER:** *We've matured long enough.*
>
> **SEVEN:** *Doubtful. Your thoracic nodes haven't formed yet. You're incomplete. You'll continue to malfunction. You must return to your
> maturation chambers. Comply.*
>
> <sub><sup>VOY: Collective</sup></sub>

---

Moving down the canon scale, the [*Official Star Trek Fact Files*](https://cdn.ecommercedns.uk/files/2/229812/5/32711355/image68689-01-merged-down.jpg) suggest that he's only a few years old, possibly as young as three or four(!)

> **Icheb's exact birth date is unknown, but it is likely to be some time
> in the early 2370’s**. He was raised by apparently loving parents,
> Leucon and Yifay, on the agrarian Brunali homeworld, and by all
> accounts he was a happy and curious child.
>
> <sup>[Star Trek Fact File: Icheb - File 52, Card 8](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Fact_Files)</sup>